# Show that all permutation group $S_{n}$ when $n\geq 3$ is not abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, permutations, symmetric-groups

Please check my proof

From Cayley's theorem every group isomorphism with permutation group,then every permutation

group $S_{n}$ when $n\geq 3$ Isomorphism with $S_{3}$

consider 
P= 
$\begin{pmatrix}
 1&2  &3 \\ 
 3&2  &1 
\end{pmatrix}$

and

$Q=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3\\ 
1 & 3 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$

the product PQ =
$\begin{pmatrix}
1 &2  &3 \\ 
 1& 3 &2 
\end{pmatrix}$

and QP =
$\begin{pmatrix}
1 &2  &3 \\ 
2 &1  &3 
\end{pmatrix}$

That shows it is not commutative

Since $S_{n}$ When $n> 3$ isomorphism with $S_{3}$

Then $S_{n}$ when $n\geq 3$ are not abelian group

Comment: What do you mean by "every group isomorphism with permutation group group?"

Comment: I imply from carley theorem that every group isomorphism with permutation group

Comment: Cayley's theorem states that every group is isomorphic to a subgroup of some permutation group. It is not true that every permutation group is isomorphic to $S_3$. However, it is true that $S_n$ for $n > 3$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to $S_3$. If you can prove this, your proof strategy will work since an abelian group cannot have a nonabelian subgroup.

Comment: @manthanomen ok thank you very much

Comment: @Fourier If the main purpose of your question is checking your own proof,  (as opposed to asking about any proof for the result in question), then you should add ([tag:proof-verification]) tag, see the [tag-info](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/proof-verification/info).

Answer (score 4):

If you insist to use Cayley's theorem, you know that every $S_n , n\geq 3$ contains a copy of $S_3$ in it (in some isomorphic form). Proving $S_3$ is not abelian sufficiently proves your claim and it is easy to show that $S_3$ is evidently not abelian.

Alternatively, the easiest is to note that if two cycles are disjoint, then they commute. One can easily find an example of two non-commuting cycles in $S_3$, and this immediately implies that $Z(S_3) \neq S$, and since $S_3 \subset S_4 \subset ... S_n$,

Then do the case work for $S_1, S_2$ and show they are abelian. They have relatively few elements so it should be easy to analyze.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the "$S_3$ argument" directly in $S_n$.

As soon as $n\ge 3$, you'll be able to build up  $\sigma:=(1i)\in S_n$ and $\tau:=(1ij)\in 
S_n $. But then:
$$\sigma\tau=(ij)$$
whereas:
$$\tau\sigma=(1j)$$
and hence $\sigma\tau\ne\tau\sigma$.